# Where to upload bundles to apple in app purchases

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, storekit

I need to add In App Purchases to my project. Where can I configure that in the developer account and where do I upload the app bundle. Specifically, there is no clear link to upload a zip file.

Comment: Have you talked with Apple yet?  They do have a support number.

Comment: Want a good guide?  Go here: http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/01/in-app-purchases-a-full-walkthrough/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please review the [In App Purchase Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/APIOverview/OverviewoftheStoreKitAPI.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH100-SW1) (You will need to be logged into  your development account). Purchased products (content, that aren't just activated features) must be hosted on your own server.

From the Guide:

> In the server product model, you
>   provide a separate server that
>   delivers products to your iOS
>   application. Server delivery is
>   appropriate for subscriptions,
>   services and content, because these
>   products can be delivered as data
>   without altering your application
>   bundle. For example, a game might
>   deliver new play environments (puzzles
>   or levels) to the application. Store
>   Kit does not define the design of your
>   server or its interactions with your
>   iOS application. You are responsible
>   for designing all interactions between
>   your iOS application and your server.
>   Further, Store Kit does not provide a
>   mechanism to identify a particular
>   user.